# Multiple Login Screens and Namespaces

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem I can't figure out, in my application I have **two login screens**, one for the **admin** the other for the **regular** user.  These login screens however point to the same controller in the same **Auth** namespace aside from that I have separated the rest of my controllers and routes into two namespaces; FrontEnd Namespace and BackEnd namespace.

Now my issue right now is when a regular user uses their credentials to login from the backend they are allowed access, I installed this package **kodein/acl** to handle roles and permissions and it seems to be working because when a user logs in to the backend now they can't do anything.  The problem now is that even though they can't do anything they are still able to redirect to admin dashboard.

What I want here is this; when a regular user tries to login to admin backend they are denied access.  I am a bit confused, i dunno how to o about it.

Do I have to create separate auth controllers and methods in both namespaces? Is that even possible? How would i go about it?

I use AngularJS for my frontend so in my route file i have this:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'admin.website.loc'], function() {
    Route::any('{url?}', function($url) {
        return view('backend.index');
    })->where(['url' => '[-a-zA-Z0-9/]+']);
});


Route::any('{url?}', function($url) {
    return view('frontend.index');
})->where(['url' => '[-a-zA-Z0-9/]+']);
```

Which catch all urls and return to a single Index page,on the front end since i use JWT for authentication it validates the token on the frontend and if invalid or not available takes the user to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of something else, maybe a temporary measure maybe permanent, i added the following code to my login function():

```
$url_parts = parse_url($request->url());
$host_parts = explode('.', $url_parts['host']);

if ($host_parts[0] == "admin")
{
    $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
    if (!$user->is('administrator'))
    {
        Auth::logout();
        return response()->json(['error' => 'You Are Not Authorized!']);
    }
}
```

first i get the request url,
then i get the "host" part of the request url and split it using '.' as the delimiter, this way i can check the subdomain.

Since my admin side uses a sub domain i check to see if the login request was from a url with the 'admin' subdomain, if it was then i check the authenticated user's role to see if they're administrator, if they are not, i log them out immediately and return an error message.

This way i don't have to create a separate function and route for the two login screens.